# How do I check if my Ubuntu is okay after reinstalling 'ubuntu-desktop' package

Tags: unity, python, desktop-environments

I did something stupid. At least I learn a lot when I break something.

- I ran ClamAV. It kept on coming with PUA (potentially unwanted application). I read online that this might mean you have a rootkit.
- I downloaded and ran rkhunter. It said that my python folder was suspicious.
- I went to the software center and removed the default python. I figured that I would just reinstall it later.

  [image]
- When I rebooted, Unity was all screwed up. I guess python is very important.
- I couldn't open a terminal with ctrl-alt-t. I couldn't do anything. So I opened the CLI and ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. I ran `apt-get autoremove`, which removed so many files.
- I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from a live USB and CD but for some reason I wouldn't boot (I am sure this is a separate problem).
- I rebooted and ran `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop && apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Thank God everything is back to normal. So I have two questions:

1. Is there anything else I should do? For example, should I reinstall anything else?
2. How can I check if anything else is broken? Is there some type of health check in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything else I should do? For example, should I reinstall anything else?

Don't think so. The reinstall of the desktop pulled in anything you needed.

> How can I check if anything else is broken? Is there some type of health check in Ubuntu?

You will run into it eventually ;)

Not sure if this is going to help but there is a "system testing" (open dash and search for those 2 words) tool in Ubuntu. It will run a dazzling amount of tests on about anything (from certificates, to wireless, audio, headphones and hundreds more). Some have you do things (like insert a headphones, flash drive etc) so it will take up some time.

Comment: I'd like to add this, removing and installing `ubuntu-desktop` is better than using `--reinstall install ubuntu-desktop`. The latter will only pull that specific package, where the former will pull any missing packages from it's dependency or recommended ones